# Video conversion from .TS to MP4 produces an error

Tags: video, video-conversion

I am am trying to convert video from my SET Top Box recording. Each recording has 3 parts with extension .TS and .idx and .rap.

I tried to upload the .ts file for all online converters but it say error (not specifying what error) and conversion to mp4 fails.

Comment: Odds are the file is encrypted. What does ffprobe say?

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully converted unencrypted .ts files using Handbrake or KDEnlive (enables removing ads, etc prior to conversion). I converted them to .mp4. You don't need the .idx or .rap files, just the .ts file.